# Join Queries together in one

Tags: mysql

I have a two queries that I joined together with UNION ALL to do a count one for mobile leads and the other for web leads.  But not exactly sure how to join the two results into one.  Here is my query:

```
  SELECT CAST( submitdate AS DATE ) as submitdate, COUNT( DISTINCT name, email, phone, `make` , `model` , `mdlyr` , `miles` ) AS webcount FROM leads WHERE email <> '' and mobile = '0' GROUP BY CAST( submitdate AS DATE )

  UNION ALL

  SELECT CAST( submitdate AS DATE ) as submitdate, COUNT( DISTINCT name, email, phone, `make` , `model` , `mdlyr` , `miles` ) AS mobilecount FROM leads WHERE email <> '' and mobile = '1' GROUP BY CAST( submitdate AS DATE )
```

But my results are two columns that says submitdate, webcount and the dates are duplicated and with counts next to them like this:

```
  submitdate | webcount
  2014-03-19 | 30
  2014-03-19 | 15
  2014-03-18 | 59
  2014-03-18 | 37
```

When I am trying to get it to look like this:

```
  submitdate | webcount | mobilecount
  2014-03-19 | 30       | 15
  2014-03-18 | 59       | 37
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a pivot approach.  Use your union, but as a "PreQuery".  I added one extra column to identify the origin as web or mobile by a character.  From that, I use that at the outer level and do a group by date, but a sum of whatever count, but only based on the web or mobile flag value.

```
select
      PQ.submitdate,
      sum( case when PQ.leadOrigin = 'W' then PQ.DateCnt else 0 end ) as WebCount,
      sum( case when PQ.leadOrigin = 'M' then PQ.DateCnt else 0 end ) as MobileCount
   from
      ( SELECT 
              CAST( submitdate AS DATE ) as submitdate, 
              MAX( 'W' ) as leadOrigin,
              COUNT( DISTINCT name, email, phone, `make` , `model` , `mdlyr` , `miles` ) AS DateCnt
           FROM 
              leads 
           WHERE 
                  email <> '' 
              and mobile = '0' 
           GROUP BY 
              CAST( submitdate AS DATE )
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 
              CAST( submitdate AS DATE ) as submitdate, 
              MAX( 'M' ) as leadOrigin,
              COUNT( DISTINCT name, email, phone, `make` , `model` , `mdlyr` , `miles` ) AS DateCnt 
           FROM 
              leads 
          WHERE email <> '' 
           and mobile = '1' 
          GROUP BY CAST( submitdate AS DATE ) ) PQ
group by
   PQ.submitdate
```

Comment: I received this error when I tried that:#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ') as WebCount, sum( case when PQ.leadOrigin = 'M' then PQ.DateCnt else 0 )' at line 3

Comment: @NickCurran, missed the "end" of the case/when clause within the SUM()

Comment: Awesome.  I will read this more and take note on how you did it for future reference too.  Thanks again!

Comment: One question, would I wrap a sum around the two sums to get a total or would it be better to do a third case and take off the mobile = part?

Comment: @NickCurran, If you wanted a grand total of both mobile and web, you would just add another column as SUM( PQ.DateCnt ) as OverallTotal

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do this query:

```
    SELECT a.submitdate, b.webcount, c.mobilecount
        FROM (
            SELECT DISTINCT CAST( submitdate AS DATE ) AS submitdate FROM leads) AS a
            INNER JOIN 
            (SELECT CAST( submitdate AS DATE ) AS submitdate, COUNT( DISTINCT name, email, phone,  `make` ,  `model` ,  `mdlyr` ,  `miles` ) AS webcount FROM leads WHERE email <> '' AND mobile =  '0' GROUP BY CAST( submitdate AS DATE )) AS b ON a.submitdate = b.submitdate
            INNER JOIN 
            (SELECT CAST( submitdate AS DATE ) AS submitdate, COUNT( DISTINCT name, email, phone,  `make` ,  `model` ,  `mdlyr` ,  `miles` ) AS mobilecount FROM leads WHERE email <>  '' AND mobile =  '1' GROUP BY CAST( submitdate AS DATE )) AS c ON b.submitdate = c.submitdate
    ORDER BY a.submitdate DESC
```

But it only gives me dates from 3/16/2014, which is when Mobile has a count higher than 0.  Is there something to add to this that will include all dates and default to 0 if there is none?